# MySQL InnoDB count(*) vs counting rows on server side

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a MySQL InnoDB table. I need to count the number of rows in the table, but I have read in many performance tuning books that count(*) does not execute very quickly. Would it be faster to count the number of rows using select count(*) or by using Select Primary_key_column and counting the rows on server side? Or is there any other alternative to count the number of rows which does not cause a performance issue in MySql InnoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the case of `COUNT(*)` of an entire table MyISAM
is very fast because it keeps a table row count internally.

In the case of `COUNT(*) ... WHERE ...`
both **MyISAM** and **InnoDB** have to really count the matching
rows. Then the speed depends mainly on the amount of disk
i/o needed to access the rows.

**MyISAM** keeps an internal cache of table meta-data like the number of rows. This means that, generally, `COUNT(*)` incurs no additional cost for a well-structured query. **InnoDB**, however, has no such cache. For a concrete example, let’s say we’re trying to paginate a query. If you have a query `SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 5,10`, let’s say, running `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users LIMIT 5,10` is essentially free with **MyISAM** but takes the same amount of time as the first query with **InnoDB**. **MySQL** has a `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` option which tells **InnoDB** to calculate the number of rows as it runs the query, which can then be retreived by executing `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`. This is very **MySQL**-specific, but can be necessary in certain situations, particularly if you use **InnoDB** for its other features (e.g., row-level locking, stored procedures, etc.).

Comment: "Then the speed depends mainly on the amount of disk i/o needed to access the rows" --- this is not really true. Very often mysql don't need to access the data and perform disk operations, since there is **indexes** in the **memory**. Also `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` works regardless storage engine

Comment: You are right with disk i/o - the idea is that the time needed to return the result is dependent on time to compute the resultset size (read and count), whereas when no `where` clause is present, with `MyISAM` - the operation is less costly - just read the metadata

Answer (score 1):

I speak in general - if you use count on client side it should be the same as if you run it on server side. This is because the sql statement is sent from the clinet (or server) to the database server and it performs the operation at serverside always.

However it is a good practice to use index to count subsets of all data, but if you are counting all the data in the table the indexes will be obsolete since the db has to count ALL the rows.

I don't know if there is runstats utility in mysql. In DB2 for example the statistics also tell the number of records in a table..and once runstats is performed the count is much much faster.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` is always faster than counting records "by hand" (like fetching only primary key column and counting length of array in, say, PHP).

In what book did you read it?

Comment: I never said I read that this was faster. I only said I read that count * executes slowly. I was only asking if that was a possible option.

Comment: Not really. Each sane engine saves number of rows somewhere, so lookup is really fast. Only case it may be slow I can imagine is described here: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/

Comment: @DrMcKay For simple count all rows from N tables, of course, but what if you have a query that is more complex and more variable? (The number of rows is not stored anywhere in this case)